# bash file set variable as epoch time

Tags: linux, bash, epoch

I have a simple bash file script that I need to get the epoch time and set a variable in the bash file as that epoch time so I can insert it as a string later in some code...

I know that :

```
date +%s
```

gives me the epoch time, but I tried the following and none seem to work...

```
epochTime=(date +%s)

epochTime=date +%s

epochTime="date +%s"
```

Many thanks in advance, I’m sure there is a way, I’m still a little new to bash files

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You want:

```
epochTime=$(date +%s)
```

Or in `sh`-compatible syntax:

```
epochTime=`date +%s`
```

The `bash` man page describes this behaviour in detail.

Comment: First one worked a charm thank you for your quick and useful response